# Как различить пояснительный и разделительный союзы ИЛИ?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, грамматика, союзы, или

Вопрос этот **важен для практики**, так как запятая ставится перед пояснительным союзом ИЛИ, но не ставится перед разделительным союзом. **Но не всегда просто их различить.**

Я сначала дам свой ответ и надеюсь услышать ваше мнение тоже.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ ОТ 28.08.22**

Я решила **поблагодарить всех участников дискуссии**, считая полезным  каждый ответ (поэтому пока все голоса мои). Но хотелось бы, чтобы вы также отметили  активных участников нашего форума, **если вам понравились их ответы.**

Также текст моих ответов **исправлен** относительно частотности употребления **в статье** двух терминов (коммуникация и синаптическая трансмиссия) с учетом замечания Александра.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На примере предложения из [статьи](https://econet.ru/articles/166173-plastichnost-mozga-kak-vse-ustroeno) "Пластичность мозга: как все устроено":

> Каждый раз, когда мы приобретаем новые знания (путем постоянной практики), коммуникация или синаптическая трансмиссия между участвующими в процессе нейронами усиливается.

**1.** Всё, что касается разбираемого предложения, отражено только в предложении до него:

> Нейроны взаимодействуют между собой посредством соединений, называемых синапсом, и эти коммуникационные пути могут восстанавливаться в течение всей жизни.

Никто не давал определение "коммуникация", а тем более "коммуникация между участвующими в процессе нейронами". Синапсы были названы коммуникационными путями (объект).

*Коммуникация* – широкое понятие (процесс). Равно *трансмиссия*. Вот так было бы правильно:

*Коммуникация, или трансмиссия, между нейронами.* Здесь, действительно, по-другому не напишешь (второй "или" не вставишь).

**2.** *Синаптическая трасмиссия* – уже подчинённое понятие. Оно не может пояснять *коммуникацию*. Чтобы поднять его статус, запятую перед ним не ставим и **даём** новое определение. Здесь выражаю благодарность Sharon за это (я прочитал так):

"Или **даем** название (разделительный ИЛИ), или **используем** название (пояснительный ИЛИ)."

Даём. Получаем:

*Коммуникация между нейронами* = *Синаптическая трансмиссия между нейронами*

Вот так было бы правильно: *Взаимодействие нейронов с помощью синапсов называется коммуникацией или синаптической трансмиссией.* Здесь можно вставить "или".

И так тоже: *Коммуникация между нейронами, или  синаптическая трансмиссия.*

Поэтому, для более чёткого понимания смысла, в исходном предложении я бы сделал рокировку:

***Коммуникация между участвующими в процессе нейронами, или синаптическая трансмиссия, усиливается.***

**Вывод**

Так в чём же разница? В структуре предложения? Здесь грамматически можно, а тут нельзя? Возвращаюсь к тому, о чём говорил раньше: только от семантики используемых понятий и их иерархических связей будет зависеть значение союза "или". В рассматриваемом предложении он **разделительный**. Запятые ставить не нужно.

Comment: С перестановкой оборота можно согласиться. Но чем аргументируется вывод, неясно. Что надо сказать: если вы даёте новое название, то должны использовать кавычки либо глагол "называется" или т.п., который их отменяет.

Comment: @oleedd Аргументировал тем, что *коммуникация* (сама по себе) и *синаптич. трансмиссия* не синонимы в этом тексте. Наподобие того, о чём пишет Розенталь в том же примечании: "В предложениях типа ***Трудно или**, лучше сказать, **скучно** потому, что это была работа дробная, мелкая* (Бел.) союз *или* является разделительным, а не пояснительным (понятия «трудно» и «скучно» не тождественны)".

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что это не одно и то же? Что усиливается либо коммуникация, либо синаптическая трансмиссия? В этих примерах Розенталя поправление (*лучше; лучше сказать; скорее*).

Comment: @oleedd Коммуникация без "между нейронами" не то же самое, что синаптич. трасмиссия. Вот так ведь можно же написать: *Коммуникация между нейронами или, как ее называют специалисты, синаптич. трансмиссия усиливается*.

Comment: Понял, но то о перестановке оборота, а не о пунктуации. У Розенталя как раз есть такие примеры: *Теперь можно сформулировать условия течения со скачком скорости, или, как говорят, со «скольжением». Электронные лампы, или, как их правильнее называют, электровакуумные приборы, изготовляются разного назначения. Такие эмоционально-оценочные, или, иначе, лирические, эпитеты часто встречаются у Пушкина. Прерогативы княжеской, или, как называет ее Княжнин, самодержавной, власти.* Запятые в таких случаях тоже ставятся.

Comment: @oleedd  Хорошие примеры. Спасибо за дискуссию!  Пока добавить нечего.

Answer (score 2):

Как это работает.

Когда у нас глагол *называть(ся)* или синонимы, то одинаковые вещи (например: *префиксы, или приставки*) представлены разными названиями: *"префиксы" или "приставки"*. Названия разные, мы не можем поставить между ними знак "=". А кавычки в таких случаях опускаются:
*Аффиксы, стоящие перед корнем, называются словом "префиксы" или словом "приставки".*
Это разные слова, они не тождественны, хоть и значение у них совпадает.
*Аффиксы, стоящие перед корнем, называются префиксами или приставками.*

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.

Answer (score 2):

**Комментарий к ответу Александра**

**1. Что такое коммуникация**

КОММУНИКАЦИЯ, -и; ж. [лат. communicatio – сообщение] **1. Спец.** Путь сообщения, связь одного места с другим. Водные коммуникации. Средства массовой коммуникации (о газетах, радио, телевидении). Энергетические коммуникации. Подвести, провести коммуникации. Подземные коммуникации. **2. Лингв.** Сообщение или передача средствами языка содержания высказывания. Акт коммуникации.

Слово «коммуникация» **понятно всем,** хотя в толковом оно отнесено к специальной терминологии (техн. или лингв.). Но есть еще **медицинский термин**, который используют только специалисты: коммуникация (сообщение) между нейронами в месте их контакта (синапса) называется **синаптической трансмиссией.**
Коммуникация – это сообщение, связь, а  трансмиссия – пересылка, передача. В данном случае значение слов сближаются.

**2. О синаптической  трансмиссии**

Из ответа Александра: *Синаптическая траНсмиссия – уже подчинённое понятие. Оно не может пояснять коммуникацию.*

Нет, это не подчиненное понятие. Медицинский термин в статье назван первый раз **как вводный в тему**, а в дальнейшем он может использоваться в статье **самостоятельно**.

**Примечание.** Слово трансмиссия известно в медицине **в различных темах:**  так, передачу возбудителей болезни тоже называют трансмиссией. В том числе под трансмиссией (передачей) понимают синаптический переход сенсорного импульса с одного нейрона на другой. Медикам все определения известны, но для популярной статьи это всего лишь **дополнительная информация**, попутное пояснение, но никак не определение.

3. **Единственное, с чем можно согласиться**, так это то, что у предложения не совсем удачная структура: «синаптическая трансмиссия» плохо вписывается в словосочетание, **прерывая падежную связь**. Можно написать, к примеру, так:

*Каждый раз, когда мы приобретаем новые знания путем постоянной практики, коммуникация между участвующими в процессе нейронами, **или  синаптическая трансмиссия (мед.),** усиливается.*

**4. Вывод**

В рассматриваемом предложении союз ИЛИ **пояснительный**. Запятые ставить нужно.

Из ответа Александра: *Так в чём же разница? В структуре предложения? Здесь грамматически можно, а тут нельзя? … В рассматриваемом предложении он **разделительный**. Запятые ставить не нужно.*

Вот такое противостояние… :))

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 27.08.22**

1. В медицине основным термином является «синаптическая трансмиссия», но для лучшего понимания популярного текста автор **сначала** использует  слово "коммуникация" и дополнительно дает к нему **пояснительную информацию**: коммуникация, или синаптическая трансмиссия.
2. Итак, **мой метод вам не понравился,** хотя я им пользуюсь давно и вполне успешно, а раньше все время путалась в этих союзах.
3. **Чтобы закончить тему,**  задам вам последний вопрос о **разделительном союзе ИЛИ**, который мы недавно активно обсуждали.

**У союза ИЛИ два значения**: выбор только одной ситуации и возможность обеих. Когда мы **даем два названия одному предмету**, то это как раз допущение обеих ситуаций. Союз ИЛИ там уместен и применяется точно по правилу.

4. А что происходит, когда ИЛИ разделительный **мы используем в тексте**:

*Каждый раз, когда мы приобретаем новые знания (путем постоянной практики), коммуникация или синаптическая трансмиссия между участвующими в процессе нейронами усиливается.*

Что же здесь делает разделительный ИЛИ и какое он имеет значение?
Короткий вариант предложения читается так: ***Коммуникация или синаптическая трансмиссия усиливается.*** Что-нибудь одно усиливается или одно из двух может усиливаться? Оба варианта неверны – здесь **нет двух предметов** вообще.

А что есть? А есть **один предмет и незаконный разделительный союз ИЛИ**, заменивший правильный пояснительный  союз (вспомним, что ИЛИ пояснительный  – это ТО ЕСТЬ).

Comment: Видите, ваш метод запутал Александра. Он хорош, но кто-то может применить его неправильно. А метод Розенталя грамматический, с ним такого быть не может. Просто вы не любите подстановки, это не детское (хоть таковым и может казаться), оно не даёт сбой.

Comment: У меня семантика (содержание) на первом месте, а грамматика – это форма для выражения этого содержания. А всякие механические приемчики и перестановки точно для детского сада. Думать там не надо – бери и переставляй, как тебе велели.  (Александр ответит, наверное, вечером.)
А вы зачем меня там обозначили – там есть люди с нашего форума, и они меня не любят. Теперь будут минусовать. Большинство у нас всегда право. «Вместе весело шагать по просторам, И конечно припевать лучше хором…»

Comment: Думать — это одно, но смысл в том, чтобы писать грамотно, не в том, чтобы тренировать мозги (не в этом здесь задача Розенталя; у него есть сборник заданий для тренировки). Найдите источник, где сказано, что подстановка — это детский приём. Понимание содержания субъективно, кто-то может неверно понимать, вы же видите. Там нельзя удалять комментарии, даже редактировать нельзя. Не думал, что вы скрываетесь.

Comment: Ну вот Александр ориентировался на  подстановку, а верно решил задачу? Грамотность должна быть не механической, а с понимаем.  У меня же там другой профиль, никто не узнавал. Да, я тоже решила больше не комментировать там ничего – стирать не получается.

Comment: Он не ориентировался по ней, так как в данном примере нельзя повторить ИЛИ. С пониманием, для этого надо прокачивать мозги, справочники не для этого. Розенталь и так много чего объясняет. Поэтому надо "семь раз отмерить", прежде чем комментировать.

Comment: Вы не совсем точны: "Медицинский термин в статье назван один раз. А вот коммуникация присутствует постоянно". В следующем за предложением абзаце термин повторяется: "эффективность синаптической трансмиссии повышается", а коммуникация повторяется 2 раза. И еще раз в разделе "Нейрогенез". Соотношение 2 : 4. И всё. //  Я исходил из основного перевода слов и тоже смотрел словари. Коммуникация – это не только пути, это передача, обмен информацией, взаимодействие, диалог, процесс. // Трансмиссия – тоже общее понятие, синаптическая трансмиссия – частный случай (это я имел в виду под "подчинённым".

Comment: Я наоборот и там, и здесь говорил о том, что подстановки не всегда работают, что правило можно трактовать шире.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец С чего вы взяли, что не всегда работают?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Здесь не просто подстановка, здесь грамматика: разделительный союз ИЛИ всегда можно повторить, а пояснительный — нельзя.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец  Я написала дополнение к вашему комментарию. посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Не понравился? Прочитайте первый комментарий. Какое там слово написано?

Comment: @Sharon  Спасибо за дискуссию!  Не скучайте.

Answer (score 1):

1. В правилах Розенталя имеется информация на эту тему, но там есть **неясные моменты**.

§ 23. Пояснительные конструкции (пункт 2)
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

**Примечания**: *1. Следует различать пояснительный союз ИЛИ (в значении ‘то есть’, перед ним ставится запятая) и разделительный союз ИЛИ (перед ним запятая не ставится, если союз **не повторяется**).
Ср.: Флексия, или окончание, имеется только у слов, относящихся к изменяемым частям речи — повторить союз нельзя, его можно заменить союзом то есть; Изменяемая часть слова в конце его называется флексией или окончанием — здесь разделительный союз **может быть повторен** (…называется или флексией, или окончанием).*

2. Давайте сравним примеры:

**(1)  Дается определение (два разных названия для одного предмета).** Здесь союз ИЛИ разделительный: *Изменяемая часть слова в конце его называется **флексией или окончанием**.*

**(2) Два разных названия используются в тексте,** причем второе название является дополнительной или пояснительной информацией. Здесь союз ИЛИ пояснительный:  ***Флексия, или окончание,** имеется только у слов, относящихся к изменяемым частям речи.*

Разница настолько понятная, что здесь трудно ошибиться.

**КОРОТКАЯ ФОРМУЛИРОВКА**: Если **даем определение**, то ИЛИ разделительный. Если **используем два названия** в тексте, то ИЛИ пояснительный

В то же время в сложных темах нужно понимать **содержание текста, а также желателен контекст.**

3. Что мне не нравится у Розенталя, так это его ФОРМАЛЬНАЯ ПРОВЕРКА: **«повторяется – не повторяется»**, она только **запутывает** пользователей и совершенно не нужна.
4. И в качестве наглядного примера я привожу **текст, где нужно определить вид союза.** Это текст не научный, а популярный (о развитии мышления у детей 5-6 лет).

**Синаптическая пластичность**

**Каждый раз, когда мы приобретаем новые знания (путем постоянной практики), коммуникация, или синаптическая трансмиссия,  между участвующими в процессе нейронами (,) усиливается.**

**Мое мнение**

Здесь обособляется **двумя запятыми** пояснительный член предложения (ИЛИ — пояснительный союз). Имеется в виду, что коммуникация может называться другим словом — "синаптическая трансмиссия".

**Для справок:** Коммуникация (как связь и общение) — от лат. «communicatio» — сообщение, передача. Трансми́ссия — (от лат. transmissio — пересылка, передача).

В популярном тексте более понятным термином является «коммуникация», а второе (более научное) название в этом предложении  используется **сначала** как **вводная пояснительная** информация.

В то же время большинство отвечающих определили союз ИЛИ **как разделительный.**

А как думаете вы?

Comment: *Что мне не нравится у Розенталя, так это его ФОРМАЛЬНАЯ ПРОВЕРКА: «повторяется – не повторяется», она только запутывает пользователей и совершенно не нужна* — протестую! Предложите способ получше.

Comment: Вы уже здесь? Это проверка для ДЕТСКОГО САДА,  а свою проверку (для взрослых пользователей) я уже предложила, читайте внимательно. Или даем название (разделительный ИЛИ), или используем название (пояснительный ИЛИ).

Comment: Эт самое, я сюда как-нить обязательно напишу!

Comment: Сидите и думайте, в чем заключается метод. Тогда будем разговаривать, ага?

Comment: Методы, которые растворены в тексте, никому не нужны. Он должен быть отмечен словом "метод".

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.

Comment: Ладно, вижу ваш метод, просто думал, что то анализ, а не метод. Методы нуждаются в соответствующем оформлении. Метод — это не анализ (что происходит), а путь (что нужно делать).

Comment: *В то же время большинство отвечающих определили союз ИЛИ как разделительный* — тоже так определил, потому что посчитал, что то разные вещи, а гуглить тот термин не хотелось.

Comment: Здесь тоже вы пишете: "только один раз".  И еще. Если вы цитируете статью, то уберите, пожалуйста, запятые. Там их нет. И да, я на работе, поэтому вы правы, свободнее буду вечером.

Answer (score 1):

**Больше информации от Розенталя:**

Примечание 2. Следует также различать такие случаи: *Буквы алфавита, или азбуки, располагаются в принятом порядке* (*или* имеет пояснительное значение «то есть»). *— Все буквы, расположенные в принятом порядке, называются алфавитом или азбукой* (*или* имеет разделительное значение: «называются или алфавитом, или азбукой»). Другой пример: *Циркуляционная, или первая космическая, скорость равна 7 километрам. — Иногда ее называют циркуляционной или первой космической скоростью.* Ср. также: *Аффиксы, стоящие перед корнем, называются префиксами или приставками. Звук «й» не образует слога, поэтому его называют неслоговым или кратким «и». Все такие частички называются формальными частями слов, а те части, которым они придают форму, — основными или вещественными частями.* **Если бы в этих примерах вместо глагола *называть* (*называться*) были, например, глаголы *являться, становиться, делаться* и т.п., то альтернатива исключалась бы и обороты с пояснительным *или* следовало бы выделить**, например: *В слове «приделать» морфема «при-» является префиксом, или приставкой.*

Comment: Вот "скорее" и "лучше" в эту тему путать не надо. Напишу  – это не значит скажу и т.д. Совершенно разные понятия, а в той теме два слова для одного и того же понятия.

Comment: Могу удалить из ответа. Удалить?

Comment: Сами-то как думаете? Конечно, удалите.

Comment: Люди-то могут в таком случае посчитать пояснительным по тупости.

Comment: У Розенталя это идёт подряд.

Comment: А вывод где?  Как вы в этих примерах различаете союзы? Мой метод можно считать приемлемым или нет? Есть примеры, где трудно определить вид союза?

Comment: Его выделил жирным.